# Oшибка AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup

Ошибка:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так?

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.avito.ru/krasnodarskiy_kray/avtomobili/suzuki-ASgBAgICAUTgtg2omSg?cd=1'

HEADER = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': '*/*'
}


def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    title = soup.find_all('div', class_='iva-item-content-UnQQ4')

    cars = []
    for item in title:
        cars.append({
            'name': item.find('h3', class_='title-root-j7cja iva-item-title-_qCwt title-listRedesign-XHq38 title-root_maxHeight-SXHes text-text-LurtD text-size-s-BxGpL text-bold-SinUO').text,
        })

    print(cars)
```

Comment: и другие [дубликаты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=AttributeError%3A+%27NoneType%27+object+has+no+attribute+%27text%27)

Comment: а что непонятно в тексте ошибки?